# Dataview Component change event executes in infinite loop

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to create a dataview component with a panel and a toggle button. The inital states of the toggle button is set by a field in the store and on clicking the toggle button, certain functions needs to be called to update the state in backend.But since I am initializing the states of toggle button from backend when page loads, the change event is called on start itself, due to which the button toggles infinitely by calling the logic inside the CHANGE EVENT part back to back.
    Kindly help as on how to prevent the change event from being called on page load and to be only called when user clicks on the toggle button?

```
    /**

var togglevalue = 0, count = 0;
Ext.define('PMDQ.view.EquipmentDVItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Toggle'
    ],
    alias: 'widget.equipmentdvitem',

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        cls: 'cartitem-cls',
        dataMap: {

            // Map product's data to dataItem setter
            getEqpmntdvinneritem: {
                setDisplayName: 'ChecklistText'
            },
            getTogglebutton: {
                setValue: "ItemValue"
            }
        },

        eqpmntdvinneritem: {
            flex: 2
        },

        togglebutton: {
            itemId: "itemspinnerfield",
            flex: 1,
            name: 'single_toggle'
        },

        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'center'
        }
    },
    applyEqpmntdvinneritem: function (config) {
        console.log(PMDQ.view.EquipmentDVInnerItem);
        return Ext.factory(config,
            PMDQ.view.EquipmentDVInnerItem,
            this.getEqpmntdvinneritem());
    },
    updateEqpmntdvinneritem: function (newItemLine, oldItemLine) {
        if (oldItemLine) {

            this.remove(oldItemLine);
        }

        if (newItemLine) {
            // Attach lines to DataView
            newItemLine.on('tap', this.onTogglebuttonTap, this);
            this.add(newItemLine);
        }
    },

    applyTogglebutton: function (config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.field.Toggle, this.getTogglebutton());
    },

    updateTogglebutton: function (newTogglebutton, oldTogglebutton) {
        if (oldTogglebutton) {
            this.remove(oldTogglebutton);
        }

        if (newTogglebutton) {
            // add an event listeners for the `tap` event onto the new button, and tell it to call the onNameButtonTap method
            // when it happens

            newTogglebutton.on('load', this.onTogglebuttonTap, this);
            newTogglebutton.on('change', this.onTogglebuttonChange, this);

            this.add(newTogglebutton);
        }
    },

        onTogglebuttonTap: function () {
        var record = this.getRecord(), me = this;
        count = 0;
    },

    onTogglebuttonChange: function (slider, newValue, oldValue, thumb) {
        var record = this.getRecord(), me = this , store = me.getStore();

            if (oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1) {
                var val = record.get("InputAllowed");
                if (val == "X") {
                    alert("onMPValueEnteronMPValueEnter" + count);
                    me.fireEvent("onMPValueEnter", this, record);
                    togglevalue = 0;
                }
                else {
                    me.fireEvent("onToggleSave", this, oldValue, newValue, record);
                    togglevalue = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (oldValue == 1 && newValue == 0) {
                alert("onToggleSave Off" + count);
                me.fireEvent("onToggleSave", this, oldValue, newValue, record);
                togglevalue = 0;
            }

    }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional in the listener which will then be set the first time that the item is "set" and thereafter you can act as you normally wanted.

So for example in the config of the toggle you could add a property to check and change on instantiation.

```
    togglebutton: {
        toggleSet: false, // <-- for example here.
        itemId: "itemspinnerfield",
        flex: 1,
        name: 'single_toggle'
    }
```

Then amend your listener to check if it's only been loaded and set the first or subsequent times:

```
onTogglebuttonChange: function (slider, newValue, oldValue, thumb) {
    // Added a conditional to check if the toggle has been initially set or not.
    if (!slider.toggleSet){
        // Now set the toggleSet so next time the listener runs, it will continue below.
       slider.toggleSet = true;
       return;
    }

    var record = this.getRecord(), me = this , store = me.getStore();

        if (oldValue == 0 && newValue == 1) {
            var val = record.get("InputAllowed");
            if (val == "X") {
                alert("onMPValueEnteronMPValueEnter" + count);
                me.fireEvent("onMPValueEnter", this, record);
                togglevalue = 0;
            }
            else {
                me.fireEvent("onToggleSave", this, oldValue, newValue, record);
                togglevalue = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (oldValue == 1 && newValue == 0) {
            alert("onToggleSave Off" + count);
            me.fireEvent("onToggleSave", this, oldValue, newValue, record);
            togglevalue = 0;
        }

}
```